# Removing elements from an ArrayList Java

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am writing a program in Android Studio. If the SeekBar gets changed, I want the ArrayList storing the elements the user has given to be removed so they can start over. Everything works great when the code chunk with the arraylist.remove() is commented out. Wondering why these few lines of code crash my program when I try to move the SeekBar. Here is my code. Both count and converter.langSize are initialized to 1 elsewhere.

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    if (seekBar.getId() == R.id.langSizeSeekBar && fromUser) {
        if (count <= converter.langSize) {
            countTextView.setText("" + (progress + 1));
            for (int i = 0; i < converter.langSize; i++) {
                if (converter.language.get(i) != null) {
                    converter.language.remove(converter.language.get(i));
                }
            }
            converter.langSize = (progress + 1);
            langMessage.setText("Please enter element #1 of the language: ");
        }
        else {
            seekBar.setClickable(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your Logcat show after the crash?

Comment: It shows an indexOutOfBounds exception

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove entries from an array that way, you need to use an Iterator.

```
Iterator itr = converter.language.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    String value = itr.next();
    if (condition) {                      
        itr.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Decrement instead of increment and it should work

```
for (int i = converter.langSize - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (converter.language.get(i) != null) {
        converter.language.remove(converter.language.get(i));
    }
}
```